# NoSQL Document DB -- What's a good use case apart from scalability?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I've spent a couple of days reading the interwebs but haven't been able to figure out the use-cases for a NoSQL document DB (not key-value store) apart from scalability.

So here's my questions, **if scalability is not my concern**, would using a NoSQL document DB make sense in any of the following scenarios:

1. If more than 40% of my models are polymorphic associations
2. What if, about 8 models need to be eager-loaded for the entire object to make sense?
3. What if, there are parts of the application that are quickly turning into [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) eg a mini-CMS embedded into the app.

What about toolchain maturity? Various Rails 3 gems? Testing frameworks?

Basically, what's a pragmatic choice to get my app to market faster? In cases where the data schema is fluid, which is a greater problem - data storage OR dealing with the data in the app?

Answer (score 3):

I believe mongodb & mongoid is a good fit for your needs

- If more than 40% of my models are polymorphic associations.

  > Mongoid inbuilt with polymorphic functionality.  You can check out here 
  >   http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html (Polymorphism section)
- What if, about 8 models need to be eager-loaded for the entire object to make sense?

  > mongoid  also got a pre built eager loading option. You can check out here http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html (Eager Loading section)
- What if, there are parts of the application that are quickly turning into EAV eg a mini-CMS embedded into the app.

  > I believe mongodb is best fit for EAV because of its way of handling unstructured schemaless data.

I have a good experience using Ruby mongoid gem for multiple projects. Its rock solid and well designed library with lot of features. Since its a rails app, you can use any different testing frameworks like rspec or cucumber for testing. check out matchers for rspec here https://github.com/evansagge/mongoid-rspec

Comment: Thanks for the reply, RameshVel. On the testing side, I was more worried about fixtures, setups and teardowns.

Comment: Is anything you've built using Mongoid available online?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda , check out www.localever.com